# Peugeot 3008 2014 1.6 turbo - engine fault at 5000rpm

Tags: engine, fuel-injection, peugeot

1. At about 5000 rpm up a hill I get an engine fault message with codes P1336 and P1339. Car gets shaky.
2. Restarting the car and the shakiness is gone. Clearing the codes and car is back to normal, runs perfect until I hit 5000rpm again. It's fairly consistent.
3. Changed spark plugs and coils to new ones, original spec. Same problem.
4. Local mechanic predicted a problem with injector #3. We added a cleaning solution to the fuel (3/4 tank). Was told to drive until tank is empty.

Did any of you encounter this problem? What are your recommendations?

Comment: And the result of (4)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are what these codes mean:

P1336: [P1336 Description](https://www.engine-codes.com/p1336.html)

P1339: [P1339 Description](https://www.autocodes.com/p1339.html)

I cannot imagine any connection to the fuel injector.  It's best, IMHO, to assume that the codes are accurate and follow that until you prove otherwise.

Most likely you have some wiring problems.  Find a better mechanic!

Comment: The first one you have referenced Incorrectly.  You have looked up P1136, not P1336.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Interestingly, the mechanic's scan tool actually specifically said that it's the injector. Unfortunately I didn't notice the scanner's model and brand.